# Can I disable "Back" on a Google add-on card?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

I'm building a Google add-on using Google Apps Script.

Is there any way to disable the **Back** button on a card (indicated below)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*This is not possible.*

#### More Information:

From the documentation on [card navigation](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/navigation) (emphasis my own):

> ...the  button **is always available** for the user to navigate from your contextual cards to your non-contextual cards.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually possible with a get around (might be a bit messy). Here is the way I did it in case someone is looking for this :

I manage all navigations from a card to another so that it doesn't stack the cards, but instead pop the current card and add the new one, so I always only have one card in the stack, therefore having no "back" button in the header of the card.

So, appart from the homepage trigger from the manifest which return directly a card.build(), I navigate from card to card using a function such as :

```
function showMainCard(e) {
    
  var card = buildMainCard();
  var nav = CardService.newNavigation().popCard().pushCard(card);
  var actionresponse =  CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
        .setNavigation(nav);

  return actionresponse.build();  
}
```

And the build[something]Card() function returns the card.build()

The only drawback is that when the add-on is reloaded, it goes back to the first card you build in the homepage trigger. In order to get around this, you need to save page navigation in userProperties when building each card.

Then, the homepageTrigger can work this way to load the right card :

```
function onLoad(e) {
  // Create the card
  switch (userProperties.getProperty("pageNavigation")) {
    case pages.MAIN:
      return buildMainCard();
    case pages.CREATE_NEW_FILE_REQUEST:
      return buildNewFileRequestCard();
    case pages.MANAGE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS:
      return buildManageDefaultOptionsCard();
    case pages.MANAGE_OPTIONS:
      return buildManageOptionsCard();
    case pages.CREATE_NEW_FILE_REQUEST_AFTER_AUTHORIZATION:
      return buildNewFileRequestCard();
    case pages.SHOW_FILE_REQUEST_DETAIL:
      return buildFileRequestDetailCard();
    case pages.EDIT_FILE_REQUEST:
      return buildEditFileRequestCard();
    default:
      console.log("Problem with navigation, main card is loaded");
      return buildMainCard();
  }
}
```

Comment: if you select an email after the homepage is open, you'd still get the back button, right?